# POST to Wordpress plugin from external source works but fails Wordpress review

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been building a wordpress plugin that displays information on the site. This data has been POSTed via cURL to a page in my plugins/[plugin_name]/inc/ directory (update.php) and runs the relevant function required to update the database. 
The pluging works fine, but when I submitted it for review, I have two remaining issues  that I can't seem to solve:

> ### 1. Allowing Direct File Access to plugin files
>
> ...avoid this by putting this code at the top of all php files:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
```

Surely I need direct access to this file to send the POST data to? Or is there another way I should do this?

> ### 2. Calling core loading files directly
>
> Including wp-config.php, wp-blog-header.php, wp-load.php, or pretty much any other WordPress core file that you have to call directly via an include is not a good idea and we cannot approve a plugin that does so unless it has a very good reason to load the file(s). It is prone to failure since not all WordPress installs have the exact same file structure.
>   
>   Usually plugins will include wp-config.php or wp-load.php in order to gain access to core WordPress functions, but there are much better ways to do this. It's best if you tie your processing functions (the ones that need but don't have access to core functions) into an action hook, such as "init" or "admin_init".
>   At the top of the same file (update.php) I have included as such:

```
require( dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))) . '\wp-load.php' );
```

Because I need to access the core wp functions and classes such as

```
$wpdb->prepare
```

And I'm not sure how I can otherwise do this. I would appreciate any help with these problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for 1. You should create a method in your plugin that handles the post data and runs the CURL request.

As for 2. I think you can get away with `global $wpdb;`
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Brill thank you! Your answer lead me down the path to where I needed to be. I also used this answer: [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/203716). See my answer below for what I did...

Comment: @jtcrow - Glad that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did, if anyone else has this question:
 **1.** I added this function and hook to my plugin file:

```
//GET POST DATA IF APPLICABLE
function wp_getpostdata() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['user'] ) && isset( $_POST['pass'] ) && isset( $_POST['op'] )) {
        require 'inc/update.php';
        exit;
    } // end if
} // end wp_getpostdata
add_action( 'init', 'wp_getpostdata' );`
```

**2.** Removed the wp-load include and added

```
global $wpdb;
```

to my update.php file as Kyra suggested. And finally...
**3.** Changed the POST target to my website address.
Works like a charm - hope others find it useful!